# Why are two versions of the same server behaving differently?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, virtual-memory

I wrote a small geoip lookup linux daemon in C++, and I'm getting two different results and I'm wondering why.

This is the source code: https://github.com/homer6/geoipd
I've checked it with valgrind for memory leaks and there weren't any.

I have two web servers, both running the same Ubuntu image on Amazon EC2 and both behind a load balancer that is ensuring they each get about the same amount of traffic. I installed the daemon on both servers and I've let them run in production for a few days now.

Everything is working as expected, but the output from "ps aux" is slightly different for the two instances.

Server 1:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME
1004     28889  0.0  6.7 640288 517692 ?       Ss   Nov09   0:03
```

Server 2:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME
1004     16587  0.0  6.7 574752 517688 ?       Ss   Nov09   0:02
```

My question is two-parted:

1. Why is there such a big difference in the virtual memory usage?
2. Why is there a difference in the resident memory usage?

Thanks in advance...

UPDATE: 
I remember checking the VM size when I first launched the processes. They were both at 574752 (or slightly under 575 MB) and they both had the same value.

Comment: Are your `ulimit`'s or `/etc/security/limits.conf` different between the 2 systems?

Comment: On Ubuntu, there is no such directory. By they are clones of the same image, so they should be identical. I ran "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max" and they both had the same value. Is that the same thing?

Comment: there isn't an entry in that file for ulimit

Comment: Oh, sorry, ulimit is a command, limits.conf is a file.  Run `ulimit -a` on each system to see the resource limits.  The close/down vote might be from someone who thinks this belongs on superuser.com SE site.  Regardless of their opinion, i think this is an excelent question.

Comment: Also, were the 2 processes run for exactly the same duration?  Could you have been checking when one of them was performing a more memory intensive task then the other?

Comment: Yes, they were both started at the same time doing the same simple unit of work. Moreover, I've been checking this for a few days now. It was at the 575MB level for a few days before I got this reading today.

Comment: Double check `/proc/28889/status` and `/proc/16587/status` files, do those report the same discrepency?

Comment: Yes they do... https://gist.github.com/1361344

Comment: Also, check `/proc/[pid]/maps` to see what differences there are in the memory mappings of the two processes.  The server 1 process should have mappings that might tell you what is causing this.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1361380

Comment: Could be just random differences in the work done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From these 2 extra lines in server 1's maps:

```
7f003ed31000-7f003ed32000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f003ed32000-7f003f532000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

it seems server 1 has allocated (but not initializing yet) memory for some object that server 2 has not yet.  This is not necessarily bad; each kernel is most likely handling the memory properly, just different.

You can run `size geoip_server.o` to make sure that the *bss* (uninitialized static data) is the same for the 2 daemons on each system:

```
[ 18:10 root@hozbox / ]# size geoip_server.o
   text    data    bss         dec         hex       filename
   77727   1088772 200003752   201170251   bfd9d4b   geoip_server.o
```

<sub>these numbers are made up as I do not have cmake 2.8.2 so I was unable to compile your code</sub>

Additionally, you can `cat /proc/meminfo` on each system to see the specifics of how each kernel is managing its memory:

```
[ 18:10 root@hozbox / ]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         443880 kB
MemFree:            7792 kB
Buffers:             788 kB
Cached:            24468 kB
SwapCached:        87512 kB
Active:           189460 kB
Inactive:         193316 kB
Active(anon):     178604 kB
Inactive(anon):   178956 kB
Active(file):      10856 kB
Inactive(file):    14360 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:             0 kB
HighFree:              0 kB
LowTotal:         443880 kB
LowFree:            7792 kB
SwapTotal:       4816892 kB
SwapFree:        3856464 kB
Dirty:                12 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        305332 kB
Mapped:             7812 kB
Shmem:                60 kB
Slab:              17628 kB
SReclaimable:       8712 kB
SUnreclaim:         8916 kB
KernelStack:        1320 kB
PageTables:         4592 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     5038832 kB
Committed_AS:    1910872 kB
VmallocTotal:     570424 kB
VmallocUsed:       32424 kB
VmallocChunk:     524124 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       4096 kB
DirectMap4k:       19392 kB
DirectMap4M:      438272 kB
```

[This research paper from the University of Alberta on Understanding Memory](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html) is a very good read and may help explain the why a difference in VSZ for the same process running on 2 different systems can be normal.

---

Some references and resources:

[procfs wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)
[Runtime Memory Measurement](http://elinux.org/Runtime_Memory_Measurement)
[Linux Kernel Documentation on /proc](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

[`man proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

> `/proc/[pid]/maps`
>   A file containing the currently mapped memory regions
>   and their access permissions. The format is:
>
> ```
> address           perms offset  dev   inode   pathname
> 08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
> 08056000-08058000 rw-p 0000d000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
> 08058000-0805b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
> 40000000-40013000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so 
> 40013000-40015000 rw-p 00012000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
> 4001f000-40135000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
> 40135000-4013e000 rw-p 00115000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
> 4013e000-40142000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> bffff000-c0000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
> ```
>
> where "*address*" is the address space in the process that it occupies,
>   "*perms*" is a set of permissions, 
>   "*offset*" is the offset into the file/whatever, "*dev*" is the 
>   device (major:minor), and "*inode*" is the
>   inode on that device. 0 indicates that no inode is associated with the
>   memory region, as the case would be with BSS (uninitialized data).

Comment: +1 for awesome information and your time! Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 3):

The VSZ size is meaningless, you can ignore it. It can be caused by any number of strange things. (If you want to try to track it down, compare the output of *cat /proc/**pid**/maps* on both machines.

As for why the RSS is a few bytes different, it's so small I wouldn't worry about it. It could just be due to stack randomization.

Comment: +1 for a useful contribution. Thank you.